# How to add navigation links (dots) to slick lightbox?

Tags: slick.js, slick-lightbox

I have [slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and [slick lightbox](https://mreq.github.io/slick-lightbox/).

The latter has no dots or navigation links. How to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since lightbox using slick itself:

1. Add `dots : true` to **dist/slick-lightbox.js** *(or rebuild coffeescript)*

```js
SlickLightbox.prototype.initSlick = function (index) {
/* Runs slick by default, using `options.slick` if provided. If `options.slick` is a function, it gets fired instead of us initializing slick. Merges in initialSlide option. */
  var additional;
  additional = { initialSlide: index, dots:true };
  //...
}
```

2. Add styles to make them available

```css
.slick-dots {
    bottom: 0;
}

.slick-dots li button::before {
    color: #9f9f9f;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button::before {
    color: white;
}
```